# How to simplify filtered iqueryable date linq expression?

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, filtering, iqueryable

I try to filter date in variable `IQueryable<MyType> itemsFiltered` from DB:

```
itemsFiltered = itemsFiltered.Where(i => i.Dataout.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy").Contains(date));
```

But I get an error `The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()`

I can rewrite expression like this:

```
                itemsFiltered = itemsFiltered.Where(i => (
                    (
                    i.Dataout.Value.Day.ToString().Length > 1 ?
                    i.Dataout.Value.Day.ToString() :
                    "0" + i.Dataout.Value.Day.ToString()
                    ) + "." + (
                    i.Dataout.Value.Month.ToString().Length > 1 ?
                    i.Dataout.Value.Month.ToString() :
                    "0" + i.Dataout.Value.Month.ToString()
                    ) + "." +
                    i.Dataout.Value.Year.ToString()).Contains(date));
```

And it works, but looks awful. How to simplify this?

**ADD**

The problem is: when the user inputs 11, it is unknown, if it means day, month (November) or year (2011).
`date` is `string`, it can be `"11"` or `"11.11"` or `"01.01"` or `"11.01.201"` and so on.

Comment: What if you write `var dateToCheck = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd.MM.yyyy");  itemsFiltered = itemsFiltered.Where(i => i.Dataout.Value.Day == dateToCheck);`

Comment: What is `date`? Why are you using `Contains` instead of `==`? Note `ToString` with a format parameter cannot be translated to SQL.

Comment: @user1672994 The problem is: when the user inputs 11, it is unknown, if it means day, month (November) or year (2011).

Comment: @NetMage date is string, please look to the **ADD** in start post

Comment: What LINQ are you using? Is it LINQ to SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / EF Core 2.1 / EF Core 3.x?

Comment: Also, what SQL Server are you connecting to?

Comment: So you want `11` to match 11th of the month or November or 2011? Can I humbly suggest this is a terrible idea? **Why** do you want this feature? _If you really want it, I'd suggest using a computed column (varchar rather than date) and searching on it - since  a LIKE on a varchar column makes more sense)._

Comment: @mjwills I disagree on the horrible idea. The default search in a couple of our internal web sites is essentially a `LIKE '%x%'` across all fields, regardless of type. This is very convenient as an end user.

Comment: @NetMage Sure - but against a `date` column? I can understand with varchar or FTS - but with a date column it smells horrible to me.

Comment: @mjwills Perhaps `11` wasn't a great example (in US Format, however, `11/` isn't bad) but `2020` is great...

Comment: @NetMage 11 is the OP's example. 2020 for sure may make _more_ sense - but isn't what the OP asked for...

Comment: @mjwills I convert desktop app to web-based. In the desktop app all of filter fields are string, including date. I am not sure that changing text date search to for example datepicker would be convenient for user. Also date stored in db like datetime, but renders in UI in `dd.MM.yyyy` format.

Comment: @NetMage EF Core 3 + SQL Server 2014 SP2

Comment: Did you try the computed column idea?

Comment: @mjwills Unfortunately I can not edit db, only read it

Comment: Do you know what locale your database is using?

Comment: @NetMage Locale? Ru-ru?

Answer (score -1):

For LINQ to EF Core, you can convert the `Date` property of the `DateTime` with the default string conversion:

```
itemsFiltered = itemsFiltered.Where(i => i.Dataout.Value.Date.ToString().Contains(date));
```

If you need the specific format so the search matches the display for the user's convenience (e.g. they might search for `"11.07"`, then use `Substring` on the standard conversion (I am not sure if the default will match your locale):

```
itemsFiltered = itemsFiltered.Select(i => new { i, sd = i.Dataout.Value.Date.ToString() }).Where(isd => (isd.sd.Substring(8,2) + "." + isd.sd.Substring(5,2) + "." + isd.sd.Substring(0,4)).Contains(date));
```